# How to solve an equation where the unknown variable is inside the integration

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics

I have an equation:

$$
\frac{1}{g}=\int_0^{\frac{1}{\delta}\sinh \frac{1}{g}} \frac{\tanh\left(0.882\, b\,\delta\sqrt{1+z^2}\right)}{\sqrt{1+z^2}}\mathrm{d}z
$$

I want to obtain the relation $b\,\delta)$, where $b>1$ and also $1>\delta>0$. Suppose we have $g=0.26$.

The problem is that, when I fix $g$, given a numerical value of $\delta$, trying to solve for $b$, *Mathematica* complains about the non-numerical value of the integrand. How can I overcome this? Here is the code I've tried:

```
g = 0.26;
fF[g_, b_, δ_] := 
  -1/g + 
    NIntegrate[Tanh[0.882*b*δ*Sqrt[1 + z^2]]/Sqrt[1 + z^2], {z, 0, Sinh[1/g]/δ}]
NSolve[fF[g, b, 0.2] == 0, b]
```

P.S.: the equation is essentially from a [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54200/superconducting-gap-temperature-dependence-how-to-calculate-this-integral) on PSE.

Comment: try `FindRoot` , and define your function to take only numeric values `fF[g_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, \[Delta]_?NumericQ]`

Comment: actually just the `NumericQ` does the trick. `NSolve` works and is faster than `FindRoot`

Comment: `g = 0.26;
fF[g_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, \[Delta]_?NumericQ] := -1/g + 
  NIntegrate[
   Tanh[0.882*b*\[Delta]*Sqrt[1 + z^2]]/Sqrt[1 + z^2], {z, 0, 
    Sinh[1/g]/\[Delta]}]
FindRoot[fF[g, b, 0.2] == 0, {b, 1}]` gives you `(* {b -> 1.01398} *)`

Comment: @belisariusisforth It get the value, however complains:"Inverse functions are being used by NSolve, so some solutions may not \
be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. " How to get rid of that?

Comment: Are you using this code?`g = 0.26; 
fF[g_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, \[Delta]_?NumericQ] := -1/g + 
  NIntegrate[
   Tanh[0.882*b*\[Delta]*Sqrt[1 + z^2]]/Sqrt[1 + z^2], {z, 0, 
    Sinh[1/g]/\[Delta]}] ; FindRoot[fF[g, b, 0.2] == 0, {b, 1}]`

Comment: @belisariusisforth I used NSolve.

Comment: So ... why are you asking _me_?

Comment: @belisariusisforth OK, FindRoot actually works fine.

Comment: @george2079 You said NSolve is faster, however it complains:"Inverse functions are being used by NSolve, so some solutions may not \ be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. " How to get rid of that?

Comment: @george2079 Also how can I confine the region of $b$, for example I want $b>1$.